# How to make an enemy shoot the player in unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a game in Unity and so far the enemy can follow the player and can point the gun at the player. The only thing I need to do now is make the enemy shoot at the player. How do I go about doing this? Here is my Enemy Class so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject gun;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = player.transform.position - gun.transform.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on if you want to use bullets that travel or just "I point and he takes damage" there are two ways.

**First Way**

Therefore you have to create a Bulletprefab and some location where it should be spawned. No when ever your enemy is facing torwards the player it can shoot (Best with a couldown). Therefor you Instantiate the bullet Prefab and then add a force to the bullet. This could look like this:

```cs
// Some Attribute
public float fireRate = 0.5f;
private float nextFire = 0.0f;

// In Update
if(Time.time > nextFire) {
    if(!Bullet)
        return;
    nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(Bullet, ShootPoint.position,ShootPoint.rotation);
    Rigidbody rb = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * bulletSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Now you could also shoot the bullet a little upwards like a grenade or set gravity false for its rigidbody so it flys straight.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FD9HZB0Jn1w) a Tutorial for shooting.

**Second Way**

You could use Raycasts shooting one straight forward and detecting what ever you hit. If it does hit a player then damage it. Simple as that

[Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Enemy.cs(26,64): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.ForceMode2D' to 'UnityEngine.ForceMode'

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Enemy.cs(20,13): error CS0103: The name 'isShootReady' does not exist in the current context

Comment: When would I say, "isShootReady = true" and, "isShootReady = false"

Comment: Oh yeah my bad u have to errase the 2D on the ForceMode (I will change it in the answere). IsShootReady would be an Attribute you add which u set true when he sees an enemy and when he shoots set it false for a time which u want so there is a delay during your shootings.

Comment: @Jack_AKA_Oscar So I updated it. You should be able to use it like this now.